# C# WPF - How to load data to datagrid in thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, datagrid

I have a problem with application freezes for a few seconds.
I loading data from XML file and deserialize to MyList.

```
public List<My20FieldsDataRecord> MyList;


...



   void ShowDataInThread()
    {
        MyGrid.DataContext = MyList;
    }

    public void ShowDane(bool inThread)
    {

        if (inThread)
        {
            Thread thr = new Thread(ShowDataInThread);
            thr.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            ShowDataInThread();
        }
    }
```

if `inThread = false` everything work fine, but application not responding for a 2-3 seconds. 
When `inThread = true` application crash.

I want do this in thread, but i was not able to understand that how it works from examples on internet. I'll be very grateful for your help, becouse i have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Doing so, you will realize your question can use some improvement to make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Besides that you would better use `Task.Run` instead of creating a Thread, you would have to use the DataGrid's `Dispatcher` to update your UI in the UI thread. Search StackOverflow (or the web) for `TPL`, `async/await`, `Dispatcher`.

Answer (score 0):

Since Microsoft introduced the async / wait approach for .NET Framework programming in .NET 4.5, the code for async methods is a lot.

You can not find any async async with as example as such as type:

```
 private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{   
     string result = await AnMethodAsync();
     textBox1.Text += result;  
}

private Task<string> AnMethodAsync()
{
   //Do somethine async
}
```

And you think this is done, the function will run async do not have to worry about hanging thead anymore, too strong.

But the problem is not so simple.
Now try to put in the AnMethodAsync () function the following code:

```
Thread.Sleep(5000);
return Task.FromResult("HoanHT");
```

Run the code above and when you press button1, the UI will hang stiff for 5s.
What the hell, I have applied async / await properly that the UI is still hanging.
After a brief look at the problem: In the AnMethodAsync function does not create any other task on the other thread. The consequence is that asyn away, but it still runs on UI thread -> UI freeze.

Then fix it, there are two ways:

Method 1: Create a new task and executable:

```
return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
      Thread.Sleep(5000);
       return "HoanHT";
   });
```

Method 2: Use Task.Delay () instead of Thread.Sleep ()

```
private async Task<string> AnMethodAsync()
{
  await Task.Delay(5000);
  return "HoanHT";
}
```

This is the way I usually do with the asynchronous problem, plus one more way is to use ConfigureAwait () for the Task but will cause minor problems.

Comment: Please note that it is dangerous to use Task.Factory.StartNew when working with code related to the UI.  For details please see https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that I've found to load data for a datagrid in the background while not blocking your UI.

First, create a lock object, and enable collection synchronization, then actually load the data on a background thread using Task.Run():

```
    private readonly object _myDataLock = new object();

    private FastObservableCollection<My20FieldsDataRecord> MyList = new FastObservableCollection<My20FieldsDataRecord>();
    private CollectionViewSource MyListCollectionView = new CollectionViewSource();

    public MyViewModelConstructor() : base()
    {
        // Other ctor code 
        // ...
        // assign the data source of the collection views
        MyListCollectionView.Source = MyList;               

        // Setup synchronization
        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(MyList, _myDataLock);
    }

    private async void LoadMyList()
    {
                // load the list
                await Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        MyList.ReplaceAll(await MyRepository.LoadMyList());
                    }
                );      
    }
```

Then in your repository you could write:

```
    public virtual async Task<IList<My20FieldsDataRecord>> LoadMyList()
    {
        var results = await this.DataContext.TwentyFieldDataRecords
           .OrderByDescending(x => x.MyDate).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        return results;
    }
```

Then you could bind in your associated view like this:

```
<controls:DataGrid Name="MyListDataGrid" Grid.Row="1"
                   ....
                   ItemsSource="{Binding MyListCollectionView.View}" 
                   ... >
```

For details, please see:

- https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html
- http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html#avoiding-context
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application